# Wordpress multisite - very long first load

Tags: wordpress

I implement page on WordPress using multisite, Polylang and Domain Mapping. Everything works fine, except that at first entering, the page loads much more than 10 seconds, it doesn't show even the title of the page or loader. It looks like it's polling the server so long.
On the server, there are other instances of wordpress and there is working properly.
I have installed W3 Total Cache but it has not eliminated the problem.

The worst thing is that the problem occurs only at the first entering the page on currently computer. When I'm entering page next time it's ok. So I can't even disabling plugins to check it and test it. In all speed tests charging out normal.
One of the services: new.banfi.pl

Any idea how to solve this problem, or at least how to induce this error every time for testing?

Comment: Sure the delay isn't on the DNS? Incidentally, it's working fine on my computer (osx, safari, UK, 50meg-fibre).

Comment: use pingdom or firebug console to see what is taking so long. With this data you'll see the root of your problem.

Comment: I use firebug and problem is with first request: get new.banfi.pl, but only at the first entering the page on currently computer.